# Interpolated Hair Cuts Through Mesh

Tags: mesh, particles

I'm trying to give a character two braid pigtails - which works out relatively well, except some of the interpolated hairs are cutting through the mesh of the body rather than going around it to reach the parent hair. This is happening particularly badly in the back.

I've tried moving the parent hair (it is a single parent hair) forward, backward, left, right - but I am constantly getting the particle hair cutting through the mesh, rather than deforming around it

Any ideas?

[image: Hair particles cut through mesh in Blender]